# Plugin is not working if Chrome Dev Tools and/or breakpoints are enable or not

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I am integrating a plugin, debugging it with Chrome Devtools I am experiencing a strange thing :

When I enable breakpoints at some lines, the plugin loads well and the expecting result is there. But if I close the devtools window or if I disable breakpoints it doesn't work, width value of a div (and probably other things) is not taken in account, avoiding the plugin to load correctly. I don't change anything in the source file between 2 page reloading.

Have you ever seen this kind of bug?
Do you know why this is happening?